# Concrete5: How to refresh a package?

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7, concrete5-5.6

I am working on a custom package that only has dashboard-related application. In other words, there are no blocks. If I update the table in the db.xml, how do I refresh the package so that the table structure is synced in the database? I can't see a Refresh button for package unlike in Block Types.

Answer (score 5):

Just update the `$pkgVersion` in the packages `controller.php` file. 
Then and go to

**Dashboard -> Extend concrete5 -> Add Functionality**

from there you should now be able to update the package.

The same approach works for Concrete 5.6, but the menu is a bit different.

> In both versions, you would have to go to the same page, where you
>   installed the packaged the first time

Answer (score 1):

**concrete5 5.7.x**

While developing, you may set the DB-entities to be generated on the fly:

Set the **Doctrine Development Mode** to ON by going to the following Dashboard page:

**Dashboard -> System & Settings -> Environment -> Database Entities.**

Don't forget to set it back to OFF when in production mode.

**concrete5 5.6.x** See [@Nicolai Krüger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2326360/nicolai-kr%C3%BCger)'s answer.